# keyboard overlap custom edittext

Tags: keyboard, android-edittext

> Greetings to all. What time I struggle with the problem. By clicking
>   on the EditText my keyboard covers half EditText. Tried to put in
>   Manifest adjustSpan - keyboard covers half EditTekst and adjustResize
>   - displays the top panel also RelativeLayout. Help solve the problem.
>   main activity layout

```
    <RelativeLayout 
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/layout_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/color_background_1">
            <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
                android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_above="@+id/linear_bottom_panel" >
                <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#5c4768" >
                </FrameLayout>
            <ListView
               android:id="@+id/right_drawer"
               android:layout_width="240dp"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:layout_gravity="start"
               android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
               android:divider="@android:color/darker_gray"
               android:dividerHeight="0.1dp"/>
            <ListView
               android:id="@+id/new_drawer"
               android:layout_width="240dp"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:layout_gravity="end"
               android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
               android:divider="@android:color/darker_gray"
               android:background="#5c4768"
               android:dividerHeight="0.1dp"/>
        </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
<LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linear_bottom_panel"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:background="@color/color_bottom_panel"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image_main_news"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_main_news_selector" />
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image_main_chat"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_main_chat_selector" />
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image_main_add_mp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_main_add_mp_selector" />
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image_main_map"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_main_map_selector" />
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image_main_user"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_main_user_selector" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progress_load"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/load_progress" />
        </RelativeLayout>
```

> this fragment layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/color_background_1" >
    <include
            android:id="@+id/discus"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            layout="@layout/layout_discus_view"
            />
            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/list_chat"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/discus"
                android:layout_above="@+id/add_message"
                android:listSelector="@drawable/listview_item_selector"
                >
            </ListView>
            <include
                android:id="@+id/add_message"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                layout="@layout/layout_add_new_message"
                />
</RelativeLayout>
```

> where adjustSpan layout @+id/add_message keyboard overlap